# Fatal error after installing Steam via Play On Linux

Tags: 11.10, wine, playonlinux, steam

I've recently installed Steam via PlayOnLinux, but every time I want to run it, it gives me a screen with:

"Fatal error: could not load module 'bin/FileSystem_Steam.dll' "

There is nothing about this error on the internet. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 3):

Install wine 1.3 - the latest development version using the [Wine PPA](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu).

Then follow the HOWTO found here [Wine App DB Steam](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19444)

Comment: I've already tried that method, but it gives me the same error.

Comment: have you tried delete/moving the ~/.wine directory and installing from scratch? A bit of googling suggested re installing steam

Comment: Just tried that, no succes :( Quite weird that this isn't a common problem... I can't find anything about it on the internet.

Comment: @Hotknife Its most likely a wine regression in the wine development version. If you have the know how you can try doing a git bisect to identify the problem [Regression Testing](http://wiki.winehq.org/RegressionTesting). Althought this is a lot of effort. Does wine 1.2 produce the same error?

Comment: I found some time to test your method, and now it works :D Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to install Steam via Playonlinux, and i've had success.

First, try to install the latest version of Playonlinux from the official website, because the one in the Software Center a little bit old version.

After downloading the .deb package, the Software Center will update the installed Playonlinux.

Then try to uninstall/reinstall steam.

On my computer the install went fine, Steam update and login successful, but I didn't try any games at all.